# Archive Table Corrupt

Tags: mysql

An `ARCHIVE` table got corrupted in my production.

I tried

```
REPAIR TABLE TBL_NAME;
```

It wasn't able to repair the table. Does only MyISAM table support repairing?

I dropped the table, recreated it and then restored it from the dump I already had.

Q1: What could have been the better option to handle this scenario? 
Q2: Why databases/tables getting corrupted so often? 
Q3: What is the best that we could do to prevent tables from getting corrupt?

Comment: Yes, only MyISAM can repair tables

Comment: Well thats fine. This answers only a little part of my question :-)

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't make it an answer :)

Comment: :-) Lets wait for the answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1: What could have been the better option to handle this scenario?**

Given the circumstances I think that what you did was the best solution. There is an `ARCHIVE` engine recovery tool called `archive_reader` that might have been able to help you recover rows if you'd not had a backup

The fact that you had backups is good and saved you here. If you want to be able to perform a full recovery it could be worth enabling binary logging or adding a replicated slave server.

**Q2: Why databases/tables getting corrupted so often?**

In normal operation they shouldn't be. I would look in your MySQL error log to see if there are any error messages that corresponded to the time of the table crash. Disk or other problems on the server could make it more likely to corrupt tables. Perhaps you've found a bug in the `ARCHIVE` engine?

**Q3: What is the best that we could do to prevent tables from getting corrupt?**

As mentioned in Q2 have a good look for error messages. If you find that you can predictably replicate crashing a table be sure to file a MySQL bug report.

Comment: Cool Fantastic answer :-).. One of my friend who is a MySQL Admin, said, in his experience, the table that corrupts most of the time was ARCHIVE engine..

Comment: Hi James; have you tried the archive_reader tool?  It doesn't actually have a repair feature as far as I can tell.

Comment: I've not used it. From what I've read about it I understand that it's able to read rows which you'd then have to load into the table somehow.

Answer (score -2):

FOR MyISAM table:-

1) Identify all corrupted tables using myisamchk

2) Repair the corrupted table using myisamchk -r

If the tables are still getting used by your application and other tables.To avoid this error message, shutdown mysqld before performing the repair, if you can afford to shutdown the DB for a while. If not, use FLUSH TABLES to force mysqld to flush any table modification that are still in memory

You can also Perform check and repair together for entire MySQL database
Example :
myisamchk --silent --force --fast --update-state .....*.MYI

Comment: It's an ARCHIVE table, not a MyISAM table so this isn't really helpful

Comment: Which is the Mysql version you are using ?

Comment: This is not really helpful.. I have clearly said that it is ARCHIVE engine.. MySQL Version is 5.5..